# How can I see how much money I have spent on each OpenAI GPT model in my Azure account?

Tags: azure-cost-management, azure-openai-service

I have deployed several OpenAI GPT models in my Azure account. E.g., I deployed the OpenAI GPT model "GPT 4 32k" as `gpt-4-32k-viet`, as shown below. How can I see how much money I have spent on each model? I couldn't find the information yet on the cost management page. E.g., I'd like to see something like "100 USD spent on gpt-4-32k, 200 USD spent on gpt-4, etc."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see how much money one has spent on each OpenAI GPT model in one's Azure account by going to:  https://portal.azure.com/ -> click on the resource name -> Cost Analysis -> Cost by resources -> Cost by services -> Cognitive services:

[image]

Result:

[image]